# Windows Azure plugin for Eclipse - Deploying multiple roles application

Tags: java, eclipse, azure

Did anyone manage to deploy, or at least run in the Azure Compute Emulator, a Java application with 2 or more roles, using the Windows Azure plugin for Eclipse?

I managed to create a working app with 1 role, but when I'm adding a new role it just doesn't work!

The emulator starts but the "Service Deployments" folder is empty.

Any help - an example for a working project / anyone who experienced that / ... - will be highly appreciated!

Edit: Here is the stack trace that I could capture:

```
C:\...\Azure05\deploy\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg: Error CloudService103 : The service configuration file does not provide a value for setting '?IsSimulationEnvironment? ' for role 'WorkerRole2' C:\...\Azure05\deploy\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg: Error CloudService103 : The service configuration file does not provide a value for setting '?RoleHostDebugger?' for r ole 'WorkerRole2' C:\...\Azure05\deploy\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg: Error CloudService103 : The service configuration file does not provide a value for setting '?StartupTaskDebugger?' fo r role 'WorkerRole2' Error when creating deployment. Exception details: Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabricException: .cscfg and .csdef do not match.    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric.ProcessModel(String ucxDir, String cscfg, DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions, ServiceDefinitionModel& sdm, Service ConfigurationModel& scm, TranslateOptions& transOpts)    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.DevelopmentFabric.DevFabric.CreateFullDeployment(String serviceDirectory, String cscfgFile, DeploymentOptions deploymentOptions)    at Microsoft.ServiceHosting.Tools.CloudServiceRun.DoActions.Run(DirectoryInfo dir, FileInfo serviceConfiguration, Boolean launchBrowser, Boolean paused, String debugger, Boolean  useIISExpress, List`1 portOverrides)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works!
I've spent hours on that...

The solution:

1. Open 'ServiceConfiguration.cscfg', under the Azure project root directory in Eclipse.
2. Make sure that every 'Role' element has 'ConfigurationSettings' and 'Certificates' child elements (even if those are empty!)

For example,

```
<Role name="WorkerRole2">
    <Instances count="1"/>
    <ConfigurationSettings>
    </ConfigurationSettings>
    <Certificates>
    </Certificates>
  </Role>
```

For some reason, those elements are not created by default when adding a role via the Windows Azure plugin for Eclipse, and it causes errors when starting the compute emulator.